# What is the most concise way to fetch a blob in Python using sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to read a BLOB type (containing a PNG image) from a row in a table from a SQLite3.db file using Python 2.7, then write that data to a new image file. I'm having a tough time making sense of how to accomplish this. This is real scratch code of essentially what I would like to accomplish...

```
c = conn.cursor()
data = c.execute("SELECT image_data FROM favicon_bitmaps WHERE index='26'")
x = open('C:\file.png', 'w')
x.write(data)
x.close
```

The c.execute is just returning some kind of cursor object and i'm not sure how to get at my data. I looked at the cursor object methods over at one of the documentation pages and my eyes just kind of glassed over... I'm not super familiar with working with SQLite3 DBs in Python, any pointers or thoughts are greatly appreciated! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the return value of `cursor.execute()`; normally you ignore it completely (and really it would have been more Pythonic of it to just return None.)

Instead, call the `.fetchone()` method of the cursor after calling `.execute()`, which returns a Row object:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT image_data FROM favicon_bitmaps WHERE index='26'")
data = c.fetchone()
with open('C:\file.png', 'wb') as x:
    x.write(data[0])
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input. I was able to create my file and get the data :) Quick question, does the fetch grab the whole row or just that one portion of the row? Visualizing the almost spread sheet like view of the contents of a SQLite DB using SQLite DB viewers, and then trying to traverse them using Python with that view in your mind is getting my brain a little lost in translation. I was able to successfully create my file though using your suggestion, so thanks! (this SQLite stuff is still kind confusing though haha)

Comment: fetch_one fetches whatever columns were specified in the SELECT.